# Mergesort dynamic array in merge function

Tags: c++

This works if I create a static array left and right (in merge function). But when I create those arrays dynamically (within the comments in merge function) it doesn't work. I am unable to find a problem. Please help

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
int *array;
void mergesort(int array[],int,int);                  
void merge(int array[],int,int,int);                  
int main()
{
  int n, start, end;
  cout<<"Enter the no. of elements: ";
  cin>>n;
//  int *array;
  array = new int(n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     cin>>array[i];
  start = 0;
  end = n - 1;
  mergesort(array,0,n-1);
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
     cout<<array[j];
   return 0;
}
void mergesort(int array[],int start,int end)
{
  int mid;                      
  if(start < end)
  {
     mid = (start + end) /2;
     mergesort(array,start,mid);
     mergesort(array,mid+1,end);
     merge(array,start,mid,end);
   }
}
void merge(int array[],int start,int mid,int end)    
{
  int i,j;
  int n1 = mid - start + 1;
  int n2 = end - mid;
  int left[20];
  int right[20];

    //int *left;
    //int *right;
    //left = new int(n1);
        //right = new int(n2);
  for(i = 0;i < n1;i++)
     left[i] = array[start + i];                
  for(j = 0;j < n2;j++)
     right[j] = array[mid + j + 1];            
  left[i] = 32767;
  right[j] = 32767;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  for(int m = start;m <= end;m++)
  {
    if(left[i] <= right[j])
    {
      array[m] = left[i];
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      array[m] = right[j];
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sixth question, time to figure out for yourself how to use the editor, and stop relying on others to edit your question into a readable state. Select your code, and hit the `{}` button to indent it.

Comment: Also, please define "it doesn't work". What doesn't work? How does it fail?

Comment: When n = 5 and I give arrays elements as 5,4,3,2,1, it gives me the output 23455. Error occurs during the call merge(A,3,3,4), it takes 2 and 5 instead of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few errors:

1. The correct way to allocate an array is:

   ```
   left = new int[n1];
   ```

   And not `left = new int(n1);` as you are doing.
2. The array sizes are incorrect. You are putting `n1+1` items in `left` and `n2+1` items in `right` (including the final `32767` value), but only allocating `n1` and `n2` elements respectively. Change the allocated size accordingly.
3. Make sure to free the memory you allocated at the end with `delete[] left` and `delete[] right`.

Comment: Thanks interjay. It works now. The for loop goes on till n1 - 1 i.e i<n1 not i<=n1 so that was not an issue. 1 and 3 rectified and it works now. thanks.

Comment: @user2044770: There are `n1` items between `0` and `n1 - 1`, and an additional one is needed for the 32767, so total should be `n1+1`.